# Printing from nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

How to print either **1 specific** value, or a select key2 values for **all key1** from a nested dictionary? The lines in my code display nothing.

**Foe example**, how to print (a single value):

```
Canon-PS-G7-X-Mark-II`
```

or (select key2 values for all key1):

```
Canon-PS-G7-X-Mark-II
Nikon-D5
Sony-alpha9
```

The dictionary (part of it) and code

```
config = {
    'g7': {},
    'd5': {},
    'a9': {},
}
config['g7']['cam_name'] = ('Canon-PS-G7-X-Mark-II')
config['d5']['cam_name'] = ('Nikon-D5')
config['a9']['cam_name'] = ('Sony-alpha9')

camtype = """
1 camera:
(config['g7']['cam_name'])

all cameras
(config[.]['cam_name'])

"""
print(camtype)
```

Comment: thank you, i tried `for key, value in d.items():` but no luck of printing it out in the `info = """blahblah""" print(info)`.

Comment: just a quick generic example for printing out. sorry, should have said  `camtype`

Comment: Try this camtypes = [i['cam_name'] for i in config.values()]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try below code:

```
config = {
'g7': {},
'd5': {},
'a9': {},
}
config['g7']['cam_name'] = ('Canon-PS-G7-X-Mark-II')
config['d5']['cam_name'] = ('Nikon-D5')
config['a9']['cam_name'] = ('Sony-alpha9')
camtype = """
1 camera:
({0})

all cameras
({1})

"""
single_camera = config['g7']['cam_name']
all_camera = ', '.join([config[k]['cam_name'] for k in config])
print(camtype.format(single_camera, all_camera))
```

output:

```
1 camera:
(Canon-PS-G7-X-Mark-II)

all cameras
(['Canon-PS-G7-X-Mark-II', 'Nikon-D5', 'Sony-alpha9'])
```

Comment: This is almost identical to my solution, however that array comprehension could improve (imo):  `', '.join(d['cam_name'] for d in config.values())`, or `', '.join([config[k]['cam_name'] for k in config])`

Comment: thanks!. this is quite good. if you have any other examples how to insert many single values among many lines of unrelated text (like: "blah blah blah `Nikon-D5` blah blah blah). right now this is doable but cumbersome with your code. the other Q is how to format when all values are displayed into a vertical list?

Comment: `print(camtype.format(single_camera, all_camera)) IndexError: tuple index out of range`

Comment: @HakariDo it's not giving any error in my machine. have you changed anything?

Comment: your code works. thank you! any way to make it a vertical list? or as a column list for a table to print out?

Comment: @HakariDo all_camera = ', \n '.join([config[k]['cam_name'] for k in config]) this will print list of all camera vertically

Answer (score 1):

I am sure someone else can do better than I.

```
config = {
    'g7': {},
    'd5': {},
    'a9': {},
}
config['g7']['cam_name'] = ('Canon-PS-G7-X-Mark-II')
config['d5']['cam_name'] = ('Nikon-D5')
config['a9']['cam_name'] = ('Sony-alpha9')

camtype = """1 camera: %s""" %(config['g7']['cam_name']) #search up python print function
allcam = [ value['cam_name'] for key, value in config.items()] #creates list with all cameras
str_allcam = "all cameras " + ', '.join( str(p) for p in allcam) # prints all cameras with a comma seperator

print(camtype +"\n" + str_allcam) # outputs a two lines because of newline seperator
```

Comment: thank you. this works the best so far. any way to make the all cameras as a vertical list? or option to insert as a column list to into a table?